# How to resolve a pullrequest review?

Tags: github, pull-request, github-codereviews

I created a pullrequest and reviewer reviewed it, posted comments and requested changes, I updated the pr with changes and resolved all the comment, but still at the bottom of the page, it shows someone requested changes and a red cross. Is there anyway options to resolve the request changes?

Answer (score 3):

Merging is probably still blocked because the reviewer has not yet changed their review from "Request Changes" to "Approved." There is nothing you can do -- it's up to the reviewer to change their status.

Comment: even when changes requested have been made?

Comment: Yes: the reviewer must manually change their review from "Request Changes" to "Approved." It's not automatic.